# Runtime Complexity of nested for loop

Tags: c++, big-o

So the answer I was thinking about was *O(log(n))* since the nested for loop *x* doubles and *y* double (log(n) * log(n)) = (log^2 (n)) which gives *log(n)*.

```
for(x=1; x<n; x = x*2)
     {
       for(y=1; y<n; y=y*2)
       {
          a += (array[y]-array[x]);
       }
     }
     i = n;
     while(i>0) 
      {
         a += array[i];
         i = i/2;
      }
      return a;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It doesn't hurt to ask an explicit question: it helps answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log(n)*log(n)` (i. e. `log²(n)`) being `O(log(n))` requires constants *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>* existing such that for any *n > n<sub>0</sub>* the inequation `log(n)*log(n) <= c*log(n)` is true; logarithms grow unbounded, though, so it's obvious that such constant *cannot* exist.

I suppose you mixed up `log²(n)` with `log(n²)`; the latter really is `O(log(n))`, as an appropriate constant is 2 (any value greater is fine, too), as `log(n²)` is mathematically equivalent to `2*log(n)`.

Continuing [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458/selbie)'s [work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54848157/1312382):

```
       n, ld(n), f(n), 2*ld²(n)

       1,     0,    1,        0
       2,     1,    3,        2
       4,     2,    7,        8
       8,     3,   13,       18
      16,     4,   21,       32
      32,     5,   31,       50
      64,     6,   43,       72
     128,     7,   57,       98
     256,     8,   73,      128
     512,     9,   91,      162
    1024,    10,  111,      200
    2048,    11,  133,      242
    4096,    12,  157,      288
    8192,    13,  183,      338
   16384,    14,  211,      392
   32768,    15,  241,      450
   65536,    16,  273,      512
  131072,    17,  307,      578
  262144,    18,  343,      648
  524288,    19,  381,      722
 1048576,    20,  421,      800
 2097152,    21,  463,      882
 4194304,    22,  507,      968
 8388608,    23,  553,     1058
16777216,    24,  601,     1152
33554432,    25,  651,     1250
```

The extended table should illustrate nicely, too, that your loop is `O(log²(n))`, not `O(log(n))`.

Sidenote: At least for powers of 2 `f(n)` is `ld²(n) + ld(n) + 1`...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.

Modify your code a little bit to count the number of inner loop iterations for any given value of N.  Something like the following:

```
unsigned long test1(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long x, y;
    int iterations = 0;

    for (x = 1; x < n; x = x * 2) {
        for (y = 1; y < n; y = y * 2) {
            iterations++;
        }
    }

    unsigned long i = n;
    while (i > 0) {
        iterations++;
        i = i / 2;
    }
    return iterations;
}
```

Now let's run it:

```
1,1
2,3
4,7
8,13
16,21
32,31
64,43
128,57
256,73
512,91
1024,111
2048,133
4096,157
8192,183
16384,211
32768,241
65536,273
131072,307
262144,343
524288,381
1048576,421
2097152,463
4194304,507
8388608,553
16777216,601
33554432,651
67108864,703
```

Now let's plot it with Excel. The sameple "x" values generated above are exponentially increasing, but we still plot it with a linear x and y axis.

[image]

Ask yourself - does that look like a graph of `y=N` or `y=lg(n)` ?

Comment: thank you very much for plotting all the points for explanation. So after looking at the graph it seems it is logarithmic.